# get all the text of elemets using XSLT irespective of the tags

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

i have a XML file and having data

```
<text>
    <DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 120%; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; PADDING-TOP: 14px">
    <FONT style="FONT-STYLE: italic; FONT-FAMILY: inherit; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">
    Spondon adsfa dtewr qewr qerm</FONT></DIV>

        <DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 120%; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">
        <FONT style="FONT-FAMILY: inherit; FONT-SIZE: 10pt"><BR/></FONT>
        </DIV>
        <DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 120%; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">
        <FONT style="FONT-FAMILY: inherit; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">
       fhretwe rtwer dfsdfhfgh dfgh dfg  sfgh sfg sfg citis with anticipated industry demand trends. Accordingly, in March 2010, the 
        Company recorded long-lived asset impairment losses of </FONT>
        <FONT style="FONT-FAMILY: inherit; COLOR: #000000; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; TEXT-DECORATION: none">
        $72 million</FONT>
        <FONT style="FONT-FAMILY: inherit; FONT-SIZE: 10pt"> 
        (Note13)to Other (charges) gains, net in the unaudited interim 
        consolidated statements of operations. The Spondon, Derby, United Kingdom 
        operations are included in the Consumer Specialties segment.</FONT></DIV></text>
```

and i want to get all the text from this file using the XSLT irrespective of the elements and tags.
is there something to get this. 
i tried this to get the text of all the elements in the source

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please note that your XML is not well formed. You need a root element wrapping the sample that you provided.

Comment: Your attempt using normalize-space() looks correct to me. In what way does the output differ from what you are looking for?

Comment: actually its working in the standalone app but if i try to configure it in main app only the first line of the XSLT is get readed by the parser and the output is not get produced

Comment: Can you provide a snippet from the app? It sounds like your issue is with the app and not the XSLT.

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
string(/)
```

**Or use**:

```
normalize-space(/)
```

**Evaluating the first XPath expression above** produces the string value of the document node -- by definition this is the concatenation (in document order) of all text nodes in the XML document.

**Evaluating the second XPath expression above** produces the same string value, from which all leading and trailing white-space characters have been removed and all intermediate sequences of white-space characters have been replaced by a single space.

**Update**:

If it is really necessary to perform an XSLT transformation, one of the shortest such is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sorry... I misread the question... That template gives you a copy of the XML... This template will strip out the markup and just give you the PCDATA.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:apply-templates />      
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something similar to an Identity Transformation.
Identity in this context refers to the mathematical property of a function returning a copy of its input
e.g.
x - 0 = x
y * 1 = y

See http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity

You may need to tweak the identity stylesheet to prevent it from producing tags and attributes.